# Mozilla browser js debug in copy command

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have page using jquery. I have a problem, when i copy text from that page its focused to textbox in same page . Its working perfect in all other browsers. How can debug this scenario in mozilla browser using debugger.
Please help me